# ¿Como imprimir todos los valores de una lista de objetos?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Estoy imprimiendo el contenido de una lista de objetos que recupero de una BD, pero cuando leo el resultado de la lista solo me imprime un solo objeto y no todos los que almacena, no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, lo que trato de hacer es enviar un email con los registros de una consulta, todo lo hace bien solo es esta cuestion de como imprimir todos los objetos de la lista en el cuerpo del correo

```html
Dim tabla As New funciones()
                Dim valor = tabla.Consultar()
                    For Each item As lstRecogerEquipos In valor
                        If Not valor Is Nothing Then
                            x = item.factura
                            y = item.fecha

                        End If

                    Next
                    cuerpoCorreo = "<html><body><div style='text-align:center'>" & _
    "<h3>Nueva Compra </h3><hr/><br/>" & _
    "<italic>Hola</italic><br/>" & _
    "<br/><table style='border-color: #666;margin: 0 auto;' cellpadding='10' >" & _
    "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Factura:</strong> </td><td>" & x & "</td></tr>" & _
    "<tr><td><strong>Fecha:</strong> </td><td>" & y & "</td></tr>" & _
    "</table>" & _
    "<div></body></html>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estas enviando todo el html al final, por lo que si ejecuta el `foreach`, probablemente solo envias el último dato almacenado en `x` y `y`, prueba:

```
cuerpoCorreo = "<html><body><div style='text-align:center'>" & _
               "<h3>Nueva Compra</h3> <hr/>" & _
               "<br/><italic>Hola</italic><br/><br/>" & _
               "<table style='border-color: #666;margin: 0 auto;' cellpadding='10' >" & _
               "<tr><thead> <td>Factura</td> <td>Fecha</td> </thead></tr>"

Dim tabla As New funciones()
Dim valor = tabla.Consultar()

For Each item As lstRecogerEquipos In valor ' Recorremos todos los elementos
    If Not valor Is Nothing Then
        x = item.factura
        y = item.fecha
        ' Los agregamos al valor actual de la variable.
        cuerpoCorreo += "<tr> <td>" & x & "</td> <td>" & y & "</td> </tr>" 
    End If
Next

cuerpoCorreo += "</table></div></body></html>"
```

---

Y a modo de *"bono"*, puedes ahorrarte una que otra linea de código haciendo lo siguiente:

*Nota: solo aplicar esto si el valor de `x` o `y` no es utilizado luego del ciclo.*

```
For Each item As lstRecogerEquipos In valor ' Recorremos todos los elementos
    If Not valor Is Nothing Then
        ' Envias el valor de item.factura y item.fecha directamente a cuerpoCorreo
        cuerpoCorreo += "<tr> <td>" & item.factura & "</td> <td>" & item.fecha & "</td> </tr>" 
    End If
Next
```

De esta forma no tienes que definir las variables `x` y `y`, pero como dije arriba, si usas esas variables luego del ciclo, no es conveniente realizarlo de la última forma.

Comment: Gracias me había hecho bolas, no sabia como concatenar =)

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, en que usas las variables `x` y `y` luego del ciclo?

Comment: @NaCI no las uso, solo estaba haciendo pruebas asignandole el valor de item.factura a esas variables y fuera del ciclo for las recuperaba para enviarlas junto con el correo pero no funcionaba asi

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que x y y obtienen nuevos valores en cada ciclo, y solo se quedan con los valores del último ciclo.

Una solución sería utilizar una cadena que concatene filas y columnas dentro de la iteración, y cuando esta termine, incluir la cadena que tiene la estructura de la tabla, donde corresponde.
Por ejemplo:

```
If Not valor Is Nothing Then
    x = item.factura
    y = item.fecha
    cadenaTabla = cadenaTabla + "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Factura:</strong> </td><td>" & x & "</td></tr>" & _"<tr><td><strong>Fecha:</strong> </td><td>" & y & "</td></tr>"
End If
```

Y luego de que termine la iteración, en tu variable cuerpoCorreo:

```
<table style='border-color: #666;margin: 0 auto;' cellpadding='10' >" & _cadenaTabla & _"</table>"
```

Comment: ok Gracias funciona perfecto =)